# ASP.NET Identity + Windows Authentication for Intranet Site

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

I am building an intranet site where users will be on the corporate domain and have different permission levels.  I'm currently using `<authentication mode="Windows"/>` to control site access, but it seems like I should be using [ASP.NET Identity](http://www.asp.net/identity/overview/getting-started/introduction-to-aspnet-identity).

For example, say my application is a dashboard for each department in the organization.  I want to create a single AD group called `DashboardUsers` and put everyone that can touch the site in this group.

I also want to restrict the views in the dashboard.  For example, I only want the IT group to see their view, and the Finance folks see theirs, etc.

***Question*** -- should I be using Windows Authentication to control access to the site, and then use ASP.NET Identity for user level permissions?

Answer (score 3):

I have done something similar to this using only WindowsAuthentication.  You can tag your actions with the Authorize Attribute:

```
[Authorize(Roles = @"DashboardUsers")]
```

As long is this user is a member of the DashboardUsers AD group they will get access to this action.  It seems like MVC magic, but it really is that simple.

Unfortunately this approach will not allow you to overload an action for different Roles as the Authorize Attribute is not part of the method's signature.  In your views, you would have to show different anchor tags based on the current users role.

ie:

```
[Authorize(Roles = @"DashboardUsers\Manager")]
public ActionResult IndexManagers()
{
..
}
```

or

```
[Authorize(Roles = @"DashboardUsers\Finance")]
public ActionResult IndexFinance()
{
..
}
```

**EDIT AFTER COMMENT:**
Since your Identity is coming from AD, you could use logic in your controller like:

```
if(User.IsInRole("Finance"))
{
..
}
else if(User.IsInRole("IT"))
{
..
}
```

And this will check which AD Group they belong too.  I know it's not very elegant, but I can't imagine mixing Windows Auth with a custom identity and managing permissions in your own db would be elegant either.

Comment: Thanks for responding.  I had started down this path originally, but I don't think it will give me enough control.  I essentially need to say, for the `Index` method of the `DashboardController`, get records from the database depending on the users role (IT, Finance, etc).  My database records are 'tagged' with the required role, so I could do something like `select * from records where role = User.Role`

Comment: @syllogistic what you have said in your comment is a very different problem from what you've described in your question. Determining what data to return based on user roles as stored in the database is not the same as authorizing access to some component of the site. If this is the issue you are up against, consider rewriting your question or posting a new one, because mambrow has posted a great answer to the current state of the question.

Answer (score 1):

I have run into this dilemma before and wound up creating a custom role provider that i used in conjunction with windows authentication.  I'm not sure you need the OWIN middleware when authenticating against AD.

```
public class MyAwesomeRoleProvider : RoleProvider
{
    public override void AddUsersToRoles(string[] usernames, string[] roleNames)
    {
        // i talk to my database via entityframework in here to add a user to a role.
    }

    // override all the methods for your own role provider
}
```

config file

```
<system.web>
    <authentication mode="Windows" />
    <roleManager enabled="true" defaultProvider="MyAwesomeRoleManager">
      <providers>
        <clear />
        <add name="MyAwesomeRoleManager" type="MyAwesomeNamespace.MyAwesomeRoleProvider" connectionStringName="MyAwesomeContext" applicationName="MyAwesomeApplication" />
      </providers>
    </roleManager>
</system.web>
```